# Azure Web API - how to communicate between services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm currently developing a SOA based architecture in Azure, using disparate Web API services (they'd probably qualify as Microservices, but I'm hesitant to use the term).

I have a service which is triggered by the Azure Scheduler. It does some "stuff" and then needs to call another Web API (via HttpClient) service to trigger something else. To do this, I need to know the URI of the 2nd service. When running locally, this is fine, as it is something like

POST http://localhost:1234/2ndService/api/action

However, when I deploy to Azure (using Internal Only as the access level), it gets an obfuscated URI, such as http://microsoft-apiapp8cf3d453-39d8-4b3b-ad00-e9d8008a9b58, which I obviously can't guess at deploy time.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem? Or have I made a fundamental error here?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relying on public http endpoints, have you considered passing messages via [queues in Azure Table Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/)?  It's very simple to do and is going to be more robust since you can take advantage of built-in features like guaranteed message delivery.

The overall idea is that Service A does some "stuff" then puts a message on queue ONE.  Service B continuously reads from queue ONE until it picks up a new message from Service A (or any other service for that matter) and then does its "STUFF".  You can continue to chain calls like this to other services that need to be notified.

If you want a more elegant solution you can look at using [Service Bus Topics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/) but the concept is basically the same.

Also, since you mentioned that your architecture is much like microservices, you can check out the new [Service Fabric](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/learning-paths/service-fabric/) which is designed for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Azure Web Apps, you may always see such properties going to the web app dashboard, then properties. When deploying from the Visual Studio, you can set the URL as you want - just checked it, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what technology do you use - is it IaaS VM? Is it Web Apps?

From my standpoint, each service should be deployed as a separate Web App (or API App, if you want). Each Web App has defined its own name as in yourwebapp.azurewebsites.net, so once you have provisioned the Web App no 1 in Azure, you know its address so you will call it from the Web App no 2.

In all the cases, you should have fully qualified domain names, and not local/internal ones.

Comment: We'll use API Apps. The issue I seem to have is I want them to all be "internal" privacy (i.e. only accessible to other API apps within the same region). This seems to make the name non-determinable (i.e. rather than yourapp.azurewebsites.net, it becomes http://microsoft-apiapp8cf3d453-39d8-4b3b-ad00-e9d8008a9b58/)

Comment: If you want control over access, you will either authenticate your APIs (most desirable), or/and you can deploy the API Apps within [App Service Environments](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-intro/) then you will be able to control the security at the VNET/Subnet level.